# Count ALL Characters in a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, count

Is there an equivalent to PHP's [`strlen`](https://www.php.net/strlen) method in Ruby?

I know about Ruby's [`String#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-count) method, but it requires that I define a set of characters to count. In my situation, I want to count ALL characters, not just certain characters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`String#size`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-size) or [`String#length`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-length) method. It will work for you.

> Returns the character length of `str.`

Example :

```
"abc 12-".size  # => 7
```